# cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired

Tags: ssl, curl

We running 2 application on amazon EC2 (**`backend.example.com`** & `frontend.example.com`). For that application, we used a paid SSL Certificate. That certificate expiration date at **2021 June**. But today, we got an error -

```
cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

We check certificate expiration date, but there was no problem (**2021 June**). Then we follow this thread - [curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611640/curl-60-ssl-certificate-problem-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate) (@Dahomz answer)

After that, when we curl `example.com` by - `curl -v --url https://backend.example.com --cacert /etc/ssl/ssl.cert/cacert.pem`, It working fine. Response like -

```
* Rebuilt URL to: https://backend.example.com/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to backend.example.com (127.0.0.1) port 443 (#0)
* found 139 certificates in /etc/ssl/ssl.cert/cacert.pem
* found 600 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ******_RSA_***_***_GCM_*****
*    server certificate verification OK
*    server certificate status verification SKIPPED
*    common name: *.example.com (matched)
*    server certificate expiration date OK
*    server certificate activation date OK
*    certificate public key: RSA
*    certificate version: #3
*    subject: OU=Domain Control Validated,OU=PositiveSSL Wildcard,CN=*.example.xyz
*    start date: Mon, 04 May 2019 00:00:00 GMT
*    expire date: Wed, 07 June 2021 23:59:59 GMT
*    issuer: C=GB,ST=Greater Manchester,L=Salford,O=Sectigo Limited,CN=Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
*    compression: NULL
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
```

But when we hit from `frontend.example.com` to `backend.example.com` by curl, it throws this error -

```
* Rebuilt URL to: https://backend.example.com/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to backend.example.com (127.0.0.1) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/ssl.cert/cacert.pem
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / *****-RSA-*****-GCM-******
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*    subject: OU=Domain Control Validated; OU=PositiveSSL Wildcard; CN=*.example.com
*    start date: Mar  4 00:00:00 2019 GMT
*    expire date: Apr  7 23:59:59 2021 GMT
*    issuer: C=GB; ST=Greater Manchester; L=Salford; O=Sectigo Limited; CN=Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
*    SSL certificate verify result: certificate has expired (10), continuing anyway.
```

My curl code -

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://backend.example.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, fopen(public_path("c.log"), 'w'));
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: **Check the whole chain** not just the leaf. Sectigo-was-Comodo, before getting the USERTrust root accepted in root stores, also chained from AddTrust, and if your curl on 'backend' is still using the chain to AddTrust that has expired. See https://support.sectigo.com/Com_KnowledgeDetailPage?Id=kA03l00000117LT .

Comment: Can you give us any hints how to solve this issue.

Comment: I used your two lines to solve my case: 

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

Comment: If you work with AWS Elastic Beanstalk (Worked for me) --> https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-expired-certificate/

Answer (score 57, accepted):

To fix the problem, remove the expired root certificate from your domain certificate.

1. Go to https://whatsmychaincert.com
2. Test Your Server
3. If they confirm you you have an expired root certificate, download and use the .crt without this certificate.

Comment: Thanks for this. I would recommend editing your answer to put the full fix first, because really setting the curl options is not a fix as the issue will still exist for other (old) clients accessing the same cert. The site whatsmychaincert.com is brilliant for diagnosing this problem - thank you!

Comment: I agree with @BlueC: the certificate fix should be highlighted first, and then add the temporary curl fix for OP

Comment: These steps fix the issue on the server side. Just as a quick note, the cert you will download at step 3 will be used in place of the old CA certificate.

Comment: Where shoild I enter those command?... in which file?

Comment: DO NOT USE SSL_VERIFYPEER = 0, this opens up your request to man in the middle attack. It's not a solution, just a temporary test and should NEVER be used in production!

Comment: As @MeanEYE says, DO NOT disable SSL verification.
More info https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER.html

Answer (score 26):

If you're having this issue with "curl" (or similar) on a Ubuntu 16 system, here's how we fixed it:

On the Ubuntu 16 system hosting the curl / app that fails:

- nano /etc/ca-certificates.conf
- Remove the line (or comment) specifying AddTrust_External_Root.crt
- apt update && apt install ca-certificates
- update-ca-certificates -f -v
- Try curl again with the URL that was failing before - hopefully it works now :)

Comment: It's not working. When we hit from frontend.abc.com to backend.abc.com by curl, it shows the same error.

Comment: @HasanHafizPasha Do you have the issue with curl (like mentioned in my post)?

Comment: Yes @mrmuggles, curl call from by front-end application

Comment: Well, it should work if you're on Ubuntu 16. Did you get any error messages running the above? Also, if you have access to the backend, the answer from @Manu is better since you will 'fix' the source.

Comment: Much the same I'm sure and thanks for solving my problem but, on my Debian system, I think `sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates` is perhaps the recommended way to "nano /etc/ca-certificates.conf" to deselect AddTrust_External_Root, so as to be sure to keep the file in a format that will be understood by the tooling.

Comment: I just ran sudo update-ca-certificates and it fixed outdated certificate on linux

Answer (score 11):

For ubuntu 14.04

Open your terminal

```
sudo su
wget https://support.sectigo.com/Com_KnowledgeDetailPage?Id=kA01N000000rfBO -O SHA-2_Root_USERTrust_RSA_Certification_Authority.crt --no-check-certificate
cp SHA-2_Root_USERTrust_RSA_Certification_Authority.crt /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/
```

Then
`dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates` and **uncheck mozilla/AddTrust_External_Root.crt** and check **mozilla/2_Root_USERTrust_RSA_Certification_Authority.crt** 

or run `sudo update-ca-certificates` for uncheck those.

Comment: Today the `DST_Root_CA_X3.crt` certificate has expired and no Let's Encrypt certificates work. To fix it, just deactivate the certificate using the `sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates` tool.

Comment: THANK YOU. I've been trying to fix this for 5 days!

Comment: Grazie mille caro :-), your hint ended a two-day nightmare. Just a small addition which made me hesitate a bit: of the first screen of dpgk-reconfigure... the right answer is "Ask", then one is presented with the list of available certs. Scroll to DST_Root_CA_X3.crt, uncheck and tab to "OK".

Answer (score 6):

You could enable `insecure` connections adding this option to your
`$HOME/.curlrc` file:

`$ echo "insecure" >> ~/.curlrc`

**Do not recommended** to keep this permanently, but, for quick and temporal solutions this is a good option.

Reference: [How to apply the changes for all HTTPS connection](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-curl-ignore-ssl-certificate-warnings-command-option/)

Comment: I found a better way without the **insecure** configuration, I shared the steps here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70011298/5078874

Answer (score 3):

It seems like your truststore is not updated with the latest trusted root. Understanding that it happened to you beginning yesterday 30th May. I am assuming that you have Sectigo as your CA.

Update your trustore and you should be able to connect.

https://support.sectigo.com/articles/Knowledge/Sectigo-AddTrust-External-CA-Root-Expiring-May-30-2020

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this on Ubuntu 22.04 in 2023 by running:

```
sed -i 's|^mozilla\/DST_Root_CA_X3\.crt|!mozilla/DST_Root_CA_X3.crt|' /etc/ca-certificates.conf
curl -sk https://letsencrypt.org/certs/isrgrootx1.pem -o /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ISRG_Root_X1.crt
update-ca-certificates --fresh
```

source: https://github.com/cloudposse/bastion/issues/67

Answer (score 0):

A permanent solution would be to reissue the SSL certificate from your provider and reinstall it on your server.

The reissued certificate would update the CA bundle.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

We have the same error. For solving your issue update your "SSLCertificateChainFile" with the newest version of your trusted SSL site. In our case is comodo.

You need to go to your trusted site and find under your certificates the "CA-CRT". Copy the content.

1. Go to your /etc/apache2/sites-available
2. Find the line wih "SSLCertificateChainFile".
3. Next edit the file and replace the content with your new CA-CRT values.
4. Then restart your web server, in our case is apache:
     service apache2 restart
      or
     systemctl restart apache2

If you can't restart apache the easy way is reboot your instance.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue, after some troubleshooting we found that the root certificates of COMODO where expired.

`Valid until    Sat, 30 May 2020 10:48:38 UTC (expired 3 days, 5 hours ago)   EXPIRED`

We tested this via: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html.
And we resolved it by downloading the certificates freshly from our reseller.

[This is the result we received about the COMODO certificates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EJOM.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had to fix this issue on a debian based server

this was due to the system use of openssl (curl depends on openssl)

here is how it went:

1. remove AddTrust_External_Root.crt from your system (usually found in `/etc/ssl/certs`)

   2. remove or comment the "mozilla/AddTrust_External_Root" line from `/etc/ca-certificates.conf`
   3. run `sudo update-ca-certificates` to update the certificates used by openssl

maybe it can help you ?

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I ran into the problem @finesse was reporting above. Since on our system the ca-certificates get updated automatically, I was quite troubled since the certificate was valid

- using curl on the command line
- using a php script with php-cli

but it did not work from the web site.

Solution was simple:

just restart php-fpm :/

Best regards,

Willi

Answer (score 0):

***change or edit the settings below:***

[image: Change these files from the server in Custome Domain SSL]

**server key** = A server key is a private encryption/decryption key used by the server.

**Intermediate Certificate (CA)** = Certificate Authority (CA) is an entity that issues digital certificates which will verify the ownership of a public key by the named subject of the certificate.

**Domain Certificate** = A domain certificate is an electronic document that is given by the Certification Authority which checks the permission of the applicant to use a specific domain name.

Comment: nobody is going to have a clue what UI that is.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the problem by running updates on my server:

`sudo yum update`

This seems to have fixed any issues with the curl certificates.