# Guzzle certificate has expired

Tags: php, curl, certificate, puppet, guzzle

I have a certificate problem that I am looking for a solution to. The guzzle post request previously worked, but the destination url host root certificate has changed.

On the ubuntu command line, the curl call was successfully fixed with `sudo update-ca-certificates`.
So when I GET the https url from the command line, it works, but not with a guzzle client using php.

The Guzzle error is:

```
cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
```

So when i use `curl https://example.com` command, its work.

I use a puppet that manages php fpm pools. I don't want to disable verification with `["verify" => false]` option. Of course it works, but it's not safe.

Answer (score 0):

For ubuntu 14:04 version you can apply [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62130528/10905723) method.
For ubuntu 16:04 or later you can apply [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62108103/10905723) method.

If you have a problem with alpine image or docker and there has no way to up to upgrade base image, you can simply add `RUN echo insecure >> ~/.curlrc` into you **Dockerfile**.

Comment: I don't think it's good style to just link to things without explaining them.